# ink! How to Execute Function in a Specific Period of Time?

Tags: ink

I'm creating a contract that holds users' funds and sends them back in a week.
I've created a `retrieve()` function (message) which does that.
Is there a way in ink! to postpone function execution for a period of time? (1 week)
Is there a way in ink! to call function on each block? (if the first option does not work)
How can I trigger that function except for explicitely calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contract logic runs on nodes in the network and each set of contract instructions are part of a single block. You cannot execute smart contract logic indefinitely like a cron job. Otherwise nodes could very quickly be overwhelmed by the number of continuous jobs running and the network would grind to a halt.

In your example, you will need to trigger the `retrieve` function after a specified amount of time from *outside* the contract. When you lock up funds, store the `block_timestamp` at which they were locked.

```rust
    pub struct LockedFunds {
        locked_at: Timestamp // use self.env().block_timestamp() here
        value: Balance
        account: AccountId
    }
```

Then in the `retrieve` function do something like

```rust
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn retrieve(
            &mut self,
            locked_id: Hash
        ) -> Result<(), Error> {
            let caller = self.env().caller();
            let mut locked = self.get_locked_funds(locked_id)?;
            if caller == locked.account {
                if self.env().transfer(caller, locked.value).is_err() {
                    return Err(Error::ContractTransferFailed);
                }
                locked.value = 0
                self.update_locked_funds(locked);
                
            }
            Ok(())
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use the `ink!` chain extension to call the `scheduler` pallet?

Comment: Yes, but the principal is still the same. You have something _external_ to `ink!` that is doing the call to the `retrieve` function. It's not native to `ink!`. Plus, you would need to incentivise a network of nodes running your customised substrate node containing the aforementioned chain extension.

Comment: Got it, thanks!